# programar inserciones semanales mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

estoy usando php con pdo y mysql en mi proyecto necesito crear horarios, descansos y las posiciones en las que tienen que estar semanalmente, debo crear 2 semanas adelante de la semana actual, pero hay algunas reglas: se deben ordenar primero por orden alfabético y se les asigna un numero, y en base a esa lista a cada uno se le asignan descansos, horarios y posiciones ya determinados dependiendo del numero que les tocó.

Mi pregunta es, como puedo programar esas inserciones en mysql, he leído que es que se utilizan programadores de eventos, pero no entiendo muy bien como utilizarlos.

gracias.

Comment: Parecería que lo que buscas es un cron job, pero no me termina de quedar claro qué es lo que quieres.

Comment: tengo 20 usuarios, a 17 se les asignan descansos, horarios y la posición en la que estarán, estos ya están definidos, uno estará sin asignaación y 2 de vacaciones por 2 semanas, al regresar esos 2 se van los siguientes 2. lo que quiero hacer es que se realicen las inserciones a cada uno automáticamente basado en algunas reglas

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tu necesitas es programar un evento en MySQL.

Un evento te permite automatizar una tarea al estilo cron jobs, podemos definir una acción o una serie de acciones que se repita periódicamente o en un momento determinado.

Estas se hacen desde el servidor MySQL

Te comparto un enlace de un post (No vale la pena que copie y pegue la info que alguien más ya escribió) y un enlace de la documentación oficial de MySQL.

**Ejemplo**: http://enreas.wikia.com/wiki/Gu%C3%ADa_Pr%C3%A1ctica_MySQL_5.1/Cap%C3%ADtulo_15:_Tareas_programadas

**Documentación**: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Espero te sirva. Saludos.